# How to get MAC address of connected Access point?

Tags: python-2.7, networking, network-programming, wireless, scapy

I am using **Scapy** to sniff access point(AP) beacon packets and also getting all AP beacon packets and it's MAC address nearby AP but I need exact **MAC address of connected AP** then How to sniff only connected AP beacon frame **or** How to filter connected AP beacon frame using scapy **or** any alternate idea.

*I am doing it in python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose alternate method i.e using command in python program

Code snippet

```
def Check_connected_ap():
    cmd =["nmcli -f BSSID,ACTIVE dev wifi list | awk '$2 ~ /yes/ {print $1}'"]
    address = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = address.communicate()
    print out
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the beacon frame is called pkt.  pkt.addr1 is the destination MAC, pkt.addr2 is the source MAC and pkt.addr3 is the MAC address of the AP.  You could write something like:

```
from scapy.all import *

def ap_mac(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11)
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8:
            print('SSID: '+%s+'  MAC:'+%s)(pk.info,pkt.addr3)
        else: pass
    else: pass

sniff(prn=ap_mac)
```

to print out all the AP MACs from beacon frames.  Then you could use something like:

```
from scapy.all import *

def sniff_ap(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.add3 == 'xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.xx':  ## AP MAC
            print(pkt.summary())
        else: pass
    else: pass

sniff(prn=sniff_ap)
```

Here is a good link re: beacon frames.  https://www.4armed.com/blog/forging-wifi-beacon-frames-using-scapy/

Comment: I need MAC address of connected Access point. please read question properly

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the question.  You asked how to find the MAC address of the Access Point from a beacon packet then filter on that MAC, right?  If so, the AP MAC is addr3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We can do with alternative way by using system call in python. I am doing that if I get let you know.