# Getting different output for same command, one in bash terminal and second in python program using subprocess library

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, subprocess

I am trying to extract MAC address of **connected** Access point(AP). If I run command(mentioned below) in bash it gives connected AP MAC address but that same command run in python code it gives MAC address all near AP and using subprocess library in python code.

*Using Python 2.7 interpreter.

command is :

> iwlist wlo1 scan | grep Address

Output of Bash terminal:

> Cell 01 - Address: 00:17:7C:43:77:E5

Python code:

```
def Check_connected_ap():
    cmd =['iwlist wlo1 scan | grep Address']
    address = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
    (out, err) = address.communicate()
    print out
```

Output of python code:

> Cell 01 - Address: 00:17:7C:43:77:E5
>
> Cell 02 - Address: 00:17:7C:5A:86:23
>
> Cell 03 - Address: 92:4C:E5:3B:AE:8B

Comment: How many times did you run each command? Do they always return same values?

Comment: I run it one time (python code)  and it gives MAC address of near AP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WiFi is scanning for beams from WiFi all the time. It is possible that when you ran the first time it only had one AP and when you ran the second time, it had 3 AP's detected. The other 2 might have very low level signal. If you run the bash command many times probably once you might see the other two.

Comment: I checked, you are right. Then how I can get only connected AP MAC address in python code. After running  many times it giving connected AP MAC address.

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918505/how-to-get-mac-address-of-connected-access-point). this is my another question about this problem

Comment: @ArunkumarTopagi, that is easy, you have the data about your connected AP. Having the SSID you are connected to, which you have, you can compare with the AP data. Check Python commands to find out how. I shouldn't be difficult